# Display a multi select pick list field in visual force - why NULL is not optional?

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I am having a visualforce page where i display a multi select picklist field.
It's a InputField so the user can change the value of the field and then save it.
The problem is that when i choosing nothing in the multi select picklist field and save it still gives me one value at the "Chosen" side. Any ideas why?
by the way, with standard pick-list field i don't have this problem...

i have checked the "save" class in my controller and it seems that the problem is with the:
pageRef.setRedirect(true) i use
but without it i the page is not refreshing automatically after the saving...
this is the full "save" class which i use:

```
public PageReference save() {
    update Pos;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Thx in advanced

Comment: I think we need to see more code to understand what's happening. However, first thing is that I would expect you to return a `null` PageReference from the save() method. Also, do you have a `<apex:pagemessages />` tag that is being rerendered on your page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined your Mult-Select picklist field with a default value?

[image]

Have you also tried returning 'null' from your [action method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_controller_navigation_methods.htm)?

Comment: No, i dont have a default value. As i wrote, the problem is with the "setRedirect" function which i need to for the page refresh.
so, acctualy, my question is
1. why this function making this problem(non-null option in multyselect field)? it just seem to have no connection between the two..
2. do i have other option for refreshing the vf page after saving?
thx!